# SetTimeout () is not doing what i wanted to do in JavaScript on Apache server

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

I am noticing SetTimeout () is not doing what I wanted to do in JavaScript  on Apache server ?

Hi there I have a timer set up in JavaScript to slow down page refreshes but its really not acting  to show the page timer is occurring. This is causing massive server host cpu that I want to stop for obvious reasons. I wanted the timer to fire every minute  but instead it fires every 8s . I dont know why. its in stand alone fetch running like this

Code snipit:

```
function _fetchUpdater(updateDiv,contentURL,checkURL,checkInterval)
{
    gUpdateDiv = updateDiv;
    gContentURL = contentURL;
    gcheckInterval = checkInterval;
    gCheckURL = checkURL;
    
    setTimeout('Check();', gcheckInterval);
}
_fetchUpdater('np_track_text', '/fetch_sql2.php', '/fetch_sql2.php', 60000);
// 60000 = 1 minute in ms

function Check()
{
   new Ajax.Request(gCheckURL,{method:'get',  onSuccess:CheckResponse});
   setTimeout('Check();',gcheckInterval);
}
```

Now this is completely running out of control . I think it was slowing it down before but no longer does this I am wondering if this timer  SetTimeout() is not available in Apache Server? As its causing a lot of problems for me at present. Thank you for looking I know you are all busy and I would like some wisdom as i dont have a lot of experience with Apache Servers. Thank you again for looking

I changed the timer threshold but it had no effect on showing this page update down This seems in the F12 debugger to show a cascade of page update 8s apart. i am not sure why this is no longer functioning. The CheckResponse provides dydnamic html from sql fetch.

Comment: I don't see PHP code here. JavaScript don't need a webserver to run

Comment: Javascript does **not** run on the (Apache) server - it runs in the browser ( ignore node.js ) - what issue are you trying to solve initially with setTimeout, you question is confused & confusing?!

Comment: Thank you both for your comments the code is running from included file generated from my php file  in my pages It is supposed to load webpage fetch_sql2.php  and load it from server  at intervals set by SetTimer() it does this, but as it loads in the F12 debugger  every 8s not set at the timer rate _fetchUpdater('np_track_text', '/fetch_sql2.php', '/fetch_sql2.php', 60000); the CheckResponse is fired when its completed in Ajax. Thank you .

Comment: Is it supposed to fetch the same data ( run same query ) every X seconds or fetch the recordset incrementally? To my mind this seems like a perfect candidate for using Server Sent Events / EventSource rather than ajax polling

Comment: I think its working now Professor ajax is working fine . Not its not supposed to work every second that would be silly as it would create massive server CPU time . The timer is supposed to loop out until its had enough time however it seems different servers i.e. SSD are much faster that the site it was on originally. No it fetches different data at different times according to what is happening elsewhere  but the feed is offline as there is two problems i think win 11 is preventing output from the elsewhere site something launching blah.php?code=me&carrot=true , the other is reading XML tags